# Classic Azure devops pipeline mechanism when manually deploy specific stage

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

have classic azure devops pipeline set like below picture.

Scenario is that bake time should be 24 hour, but I manually deploy the **Prod NCUS** and the following after stage child tasks are also auto deployed like the **test** and **health check**.
Found out that after the **bake time** complete, it not auto trigger the child tasks like **Prod NCUS** again

My question is that what is the mechanism that why

1. Once the **bake time** completed, it not trigger the child tasks
2. I already checked the after stage documents(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops) and cannot find related info to explain it, any document on the details on it?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the answer is mostly just applying common sense to the scenario. You have a stage that's supposed to run after an earlier stage completes. You decided to run it early. When the prior stage completes, it's **already been run**. Why should it run again?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you could refer to this [document statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/releases?view=azure-devops#:%7E:text=A%20deployment%20is,and%20select%20deploy) below, there is the detailed description for deployment action and stage.

> A deployment is the action of running the tasks for one stage, which can include running automated tests, deploying build artifacts, and whatever other actions are specified for that stage. Initiating a release starts each deployment based on the settings and policies defined in the original release pipeline. There can be multiple deployments of each release even for one stage. When a deployment of a release fails for a stage, you can redeploy the same release to that stage. To redeploy a release, simply navigate to the release you want to deploy and select deploy.